# Center a div element within body

Tags: html, css

Markup for the div that I'm trying to center within the body. I want the centering to occur at 768px.

```
<div class="aside">
  <h2>CONNECT WITH ME</h2>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/7637603/cerrach"><img style="height: 75px; width: 75px" src="assets/images/stack.png" alt="Stack Overflow"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://github.com/cerrach"><img style="height: 75px; width: 75px" src="assets/images/git.png" alt="Github"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/christopher-cerrachio-131030138/"><img style="height: 75px; width: 75px" src="assets/images/in.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Styling for said div

```
.aside{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 40%;
  background: #7EA8BE;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #C2948A;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Antic Slab', sans-serif;
 }
```

Media Query for said div

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

 .aside{
   width: 90%;
   clear: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
 }
```

I've looked extensively for a remedy for why this div is not centering itself, but all I can really find is the `margin: 0 auto;` answer.

If all of this is not enough information, I implore you to clone this repository.

https://github.com/cerrach/Responsive-Portfolio.git

Comment: Center horizontally or vertically?

Comment: @cale_b horizontally

Comment: If you're trying to center `.aside`, you need to remove `float` from it in your media query: `float: none;`

Comment: @cale_b ill try hold on

Comment: this worked.. thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `.aside` is not centering is due to the fact that it has `float: left` on it.

Remove the `float` by adding `float: none` to the media query, and it will work properly.

See the below working snippet:

```css
.aside{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 40%;
  background: #7EA8BE;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #C2948A;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Antic Slab', sans-serif;
 }
 
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
 .aside{
   width: 90%;
   float: none;
   clear: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="aside">
  <h2>CONNECT WITH ME</h2>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/7637603/cerrach"><img style="height: 75px; width: 75px" src="assets/images/stack.png" alt="Stack Overflow"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://github.com/cerrach"><img style="height: 75px; width: 75px" src="assets/images/git.png" alt="Github"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/christopher-cerrachio-131030138/"><img style="height: 75px; width: 75px" src="assets/images/in.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the float:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

 .aside{
   width: 90%;
   float: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

P.s. instead of imploring to clone a ripo, simply create a snippet here on SO :)

Comment: this is the same solution proposed by @cale_b. This worked just fine. Thanks